What is the bound of the convex combination of orthonormal polynomials?
Let $(P_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$ be a set of polynomials orthonormal with respect to some orthogonality weight $w(x)$ in some interval $[a,b]$, i.e.
$$
\int_a^b P_m(x)P_n(x)w(x)\mathrm{d}x = \delta_{m,n}\tag{1}
$$
where $\delta_{m,n}$ is the Kronecker delta. Now let $f(x)$ be some convex combination of $(P_n(x))_{n=0}^\infty$,
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nP_n(x);\quad c_n\geq 0;\ \sum_n c_n = 1 \tag{2}
$$
What is the bound on $f(x)$?

Are you assuming that there is only one bound?

Are you interested in a general result or only in your previous closed post about Laguerre polynomials ?

@Abezhiko I closed the previous post due to a mistake on my part, and, instead of asking specifically about Laguerre polynomials, I'd like to know about the property in general.

@hendlim  Okay, I see. However, make sure you don't fall into the trap of XY problems (cf. https://xyproblem.info/); if you are ultimately interested in the positivity of convex combinations of distributions, you should ask directly about it or give some  explicit context to the present question (its relavancy and your personal thoughts for for instance) in order to avoid to waste time on a wrong direction.

@hendlim   As a partial answer : if the interval $[a,b]$ is not finite, for example with Laguerre polynomials, then it is easy to construct a counter-example, such as $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}L_0(x) + \frac{1}{2}L_1(x) = -x$, which is clearly unbounded towards $+\infty$.
